# Django 2.2.5, Multiple User Types with Django's built-in authentication system

Tags: python, django, authentication, web

I am creating a web application, there are 3 types of users superuser, taker and employer how could I implement this by using default authentication of Django.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do this. I would recommend you to keep only one user model (Django’s default or a extended version of it) and then creating several profile. Each profile is a different model with the information related to the user type. This approach has worked for my in the past, but you would need to share more information so we can really know if this is a good approach.

I suggest you to read the post by Vítor Freitas where he explains different strategies, included the one I shared.

Link: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/01/18/how-to-implement-multiple-user-types-with-django.html